How to BigQuery json "struct" to rows?
I have a table with extracted currency exchange rates refreshing every day. It's schema is Date_field / JSON_field
I need to "unnest" the json to be able to use it further with BigQuery sql as far as I believe.
The final json part that I can't trim down more looks like that: {"AED":3.6725,"AFN":94.0551,"ALL":107.9775,"AMD":480.2637,"ANG":1.79,"AOA":590.8707,....}
I have tried different json commands _query,_value,_extract etc. Tried turning it to string and replacing braces but it is not recognized as an array. I am probably missing something simple (at least I hope so) so I would appreciate the advice. Is that possible thorugh BigQuery sql alone?
Thanks in advance for your time!

Consider below approach
select as struct trim(y[0], '"') as key, y[1] as value
from exchange_rates, 
unnest(split(trim(json, '{}'))) as x, 
unnest([struct(split(x, ':') as y)])   

If applied to sample data in y our question
with exchange_rates as (
  select '{"AED":3.6725,"AFN":94.0551,"ALL":107.9775,"AMD":480.2637,"ANG":1.79,"AOA":590.8707}' as json 
)

output is


Thank you very much! It worked like a charm after changing json into string type!

Your JSON is not an array but is instead a JSON object ... i.e. a single item with a set of named fields.  Assuming you want an array as output with each element of the array being a STRUCT with a name and a value field, one way to solve the problem would be to explicitly identify each of the potential currencies:
WITH parsed_json AS (
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"AED": 3.6725, "AFN": 94.0551}') as json
)
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT STRUCT( "AED" as name, JSON_VALUE(json, "$.AED") as value) FROM parsed_json
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT STRUCT( "AFN" as name, JSON_VALUE(json, "$.AFN") as value) FROM parsed_json
) as records

However, perhaps a more elegant and dynamic solution looks as follows:
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION to_array(data JSON)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value STRING>>
LANGUAGE js
AS r"""
const ret = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  ret.push({"name": key, "value": value})
}
return ret;
""";

SELECT to_array(PARSE_JSON('{"AED": 3.6725, "AFN": 94.0551}')) AS records

We take advantage of the notion that we can create a UDF written in JavaScript.  We then translate the object into an array equivalent where each element of the array is the name/value pair of the field in the object.
An example of output:


Thank you for your answer! It's really interesting but how do I make it work for more than 1 row at a time? Like I have a whole column of these jsons attached to every date (clarification: 1 date = 1 json)

SELECT to_array(json_column_name) AS records FROM myInputTable

Since you mentioned the schema has JSON Field. You can simply use the Unnest Function in BigQuery
WITH json_data AS (
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(
    '[{"currency": "AED", "rate": 3.6725}, {"currency": "AFN", "rate": 94.0551}, {"currency": "ALL", "rate": 107.9775}, {"currency": "AMD", "rate": 480.2637}, {"currency": "ANG", "rate": 1.79}, {"currency": "AOA", "rate": 590.8707}]',
    '$'
  ) AS json_array
)
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(item, '$.currency') AS currency,
  CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(item, '$.rate') AS numeric) AS rate
FROM json_data,
  UNNEST(json_array) AS item




BigQuery actually has a JSON data type that may be better than a STRUCT:
WITH example AS (
  SELECT '{"AED":3.6725,"AFN":94.0551,"ALL":107.9775,"AMD":480.2637,"ANG":1.79,"AOA":590.8707}' AS json_str
)
SELECT 
  CAST(json_str AS JSON) AS json_object
FROM example;

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/json-data
But if you want a struct type specifically it could be done like this:
WITH example AS (
  SELECT '{"AED":3.6725,"AFN":94.0551,"ALL":107.9775,"AMD":480.2637,"ANG":1.79,"AOA":590.8707}' AS json_str
)
SELECT 
  CAST( 
    (
      SELECT AS STRUCT
        CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_str, '$.AED') AS FLOAT64) AS AED,
        CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_str, '$.AFN') AS FLOAT64) AS AFN,
        CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_str, '$.ALL') AS FLOAT64) AS ALL,
        CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_str, '$.AMD') AS FLOAT64) AS AMD,
        CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_str, '$.ANG') AS FLOAT64) AS ANG,
        CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_str, '$.AOA') AS FLOAT64) AS AOA
    ) AS STRUCT<AED FLOAT64, AFN FLOAT64, ALL FLOAT64, AMD FLOAT64, ANG FLOAT64, AOA FLOAT64>
  ) AS currency_struct
FROM example;

